# how do I access a CentOS 7 file system from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, centos, xfs

I am using an [Apricorn SATA Wire](http://www.apricorn.com/sata-wire-3.html) to connect a hard drive removed from another PC to the USB drive of a Windows 8.1 machine.  The external hard drive is from a machine that had both CentOS 7 and Windows 7 installed in a dual boot setup.  I can view the Windows files from Windows explorer, but **how do I access and view/import the CentOS 7 files on the external hard drive?**

This no doubt involves being able to access the partition in the external drive that was allocated to CentOS 7, which is different from the partition that houses the Windows files.  It also probably involves managing a different formatting protocol.

Step by step instructions would be much appreciated.

Comment: That would have been helpful to say. I've updated the tags.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options. You could run something like coLinux. But there are a couple of drivers available:

- [Captain Nemo Pro](https://www.runtime.org/captain-nemo.htm) currently around USD90
- [Crossmeta File System Drivers](http://www.pavitrasoft.com/crossmeta.html)

Not tried either of them I'm afraid but both claim XFS support.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this.  Captain Nemo was not able to see the meaningful content in the old detached CentOS drive, though it could see the windows portion and some unimportant aspects of the XFS portion.  I tried Crossmeta, but it caused my system to crash so that I had to use system utilities to restore windows to an earlier state.  I am going to pursue other options because I do not want my system to crash again.  But thank you for your time.

Comment: OK, sorry about that, thanks for letting us know. Maybe you will have to take the round-about route of a local VM. You could create a small Linux VM using VirtualBox in order to expose the physical drive via the VB network.